# is it possible to make a computed-property lazy

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, vuejs3, vue-component

as shown in the below posted code, in `compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled`, it checks first if `digitizePolygonInteractions` is initialized or not, if it is not initialized, an error will be thrown.

at the time of execution,initially, the `digitizePolygonInteractions` is not initialized yet, and the `compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled` behaves as if it is eager not lazy,thus the error is always thrown because by the time the computer-property executes, the `digitizePolygonInteractions`
is not initilized.

my questions are:
1-is it possible to make compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled` lazy not eager?

2- how to display value of `digitizePolygonInteractions` within the thrown error

**code**:

```
computed: {
    compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled() {
        if (digitizePolygonInteractions) {
            if (isBtnDigitizePolygonClicked.value == true) {
                digitizePolygonInteractions.remove();
                return values.CONST_STRING_DIGITIZE;
            } else {
                digitizePolygonInteractions.add();
                return values.CONST_STRING_STOP_DIGITIZE;
            }
        } else {
            throw new Error('WTF.digitizePolygonInteractions is:', digitizePolygonInteractions)
        }
    },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to make compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled` lazy not
> eager ?

Ideally, computed properties in `Vue` are eagerly by default but to make it `lazy` you can use data `property` and `watcher` together.

Example **:**

```
data() {
  return  {
    isComputedPropertyInitialized: false
  }
},
computed: {
  compPropsIsBtnDigitizePolygonDisabled() {
    if (!this.isComputedPropertyInitialized) {
      return;
    } else {
      // You can add your logic here
    }
  }
},
watch: {
  digitizePolygonInteractions(value) {
    if (!this.isComputedPropertyInitialized && value) {
      this.isComputedPropertyInitialized = true;
    }
  }
}
```

> How to display value of `digitizePolygonInteractions` within the
> thrown error ?

You can concatenate the error by using `+` operator in your `Error` function call.

```
throw new Error('WTF.digitizePolygonInteractions is: ' + digitizePolygonInteractions)
```

Comment: _"Ideally, computed properties in `Vue` are eagerly by default"_ since when? AFAIK computed properties are lazily evaluated.

Comment: @Marco eagerly meaning they are recalculated immediately when their dependencies change and it is happening since Vue introduced the computed property concept.

Comment: I would like to know please whether or not I should declare  ‘ isComputedPropertyInitialized’ as = ref(true)?